# Messages deleted in chat room re-appear after re-enter the chat room

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsarray, nsdictionary

This below code is fired when I press delete button after selecting messages I want to delete in chat room.

```
- (void)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    if (arrayToDelete.count) {
        for (NSString *str in arrayToDelete) {
            NSLog(@"msgID --> %@",str);

            [self.chatModel.dataSource removeObject:str]; //??? Remove data from the screen

            [[FMDBManager sharedInstance] deleteMessageByMessageId:str]; //??? Delete data from database

        }
        [arrayToDelete removeAllObjects];
        [self.chatTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

This line successfully removes selected messages from the chat room.

```
[self.chatModel.dataSource removeObject:str]; //??? Remove data from the screen
```

When I go out the chat room and re-enter, those messages still exist, so I have this line below.

```
[[FMDBManager sharedInstance] deleteMessageByMessageId:str]; //??? Delete data from database
```

I think the above line should delete those selected messages from the database but when I re-enter the chat room I still see those messages. Here below are related code to that.

```
- (void)deleteMessageByMessageId:(NSString *)messageId {
    FMDatabase *db = [self getterDataBase];
    [db open];

    NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM message WHERE messageId = '%@'",messageId];
    BOOL status = [db executeUpdate:sqlString];
    NSLog(@"Delete MessageById:%@ Status:%d",messageId,status);
    [db close];
}
```

I've found that when chat room calls viewDidLoad it will eventually call the method callBackGetChannelLogNew where server will sync-up data with chat room tableview and local database.

```
- (void)callBackGetChannelLogNew:(NSDictionary *)resultDataDic status:(enumAPI_STATUS)eAPI_STATUS {

    if (isFirstTimeUpdate) {

    }

    if (eAPI_STATUS == API_STATUS_SUCCEE) {

        NSString *readString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",resultDataDic[@"read_arr"]];

        if ([readString isEqualToString:@""]) {

            // NSLog(@"read_arr is empty");
        }

        else {
            NSArray *read_arr=resultDataDic[@"read_arr"];
            // Copy read_arr
            self.readArray=[read_arr mutableCopy];
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^{
                [self dealWithReadArray:read_arr];
            });
        }
        NSArray *data = [resultDataDic objectForKey:@"msg"];
        if (data.count > 0) {
            apiHaveData = YES;
        } else {
            apiHaveData = NO;
            self.loadIngView.hidden = YES;
            isLoadingData = NO;
            return;
        }
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^{

            // Reverse order of data
            NSArray* reversedArray = [[data reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
            NSMutableArray *messageFromOtherArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            NSMutableArray *messageAllArray = [NSMutableArray new];

            for (int i = 0; i < reversedArray.count; i++) {
                NSDictionary *_dic = reversedArray[i];

                NSString *fromId = [_dic objectForKey:@"fid"];

                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_dic objectForKey:@"say"]];

                if ([ObjectManager getChatMessageKindWithString:message] == MessageTypeText) {
                    message = [ObjectManager decryptWithString:message];
                }

                NSString *messageId = [_dic objectForKey:@"mid"];
                NSString *toId = [_dic objectForKey:@"tid"];
                NSDateFormatter *_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                _formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
                NSDate *date_t = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[_dic objectForKey:@"t"] doubleValue]/1000.0]; //換算成日期
                NSString *stringDate = [_formatter stringFromDate:date_t];

                NSString *sendDate = stringDate;
                NSString *lid = _dic[@"lid"];

                NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              fromId,@"fromId",
                                              message,@"message",
                                              messageId,@"messageId",
                                              sendDate,@"sendDate",
                                              toId,@"toId",
                                              lid,@"lid",
                                              nil];
                NSString *isRead;
                if (_chatRoomType == ChatRoomTypePrivate) {
                    if ([_dic[@"r"] intValue]) {
                        isRead = @"1";
                        myDic[@"isRead"] = isRead;
                        lastReadMessageId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",messageId];
                    }
                }

                if (i == 0) {
                    if (lidForAPI != [_dic[@"lid"] intValue]) {
                        lidForAPI = [_dic[@"lid"] intValue];
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            apiHaveData = NO;
                            self.loadIngView.hidden = YES;
                            isLoadingData = NO;
                        });
                        return ;
                    }

                }

                if (![myDic[@"fromId"] isEqualToString:[User sharedUser].account]) {
                    [messageFromOtherArray addObject:myDic];
                }

                if (_chatRoomType == ChatRoomTypeGroup) {
                    [myDic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isGroupMessage"];
                }

                [myDic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"did_I_Read"];

                [messageAllArray addObject:myDic];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self setupViewWithMessageArray:messageAllArray]; //???? Here server sync-up data with tableview
            });
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                if (_chatRoomType == ChatRoomTypePrivate) {
                    if (messageFromOtherArray.count > 0 && isUplaodLastRead == NO) {
                        isUplaodLastRead = YES;
                        NSDictionary *lastReadMsgDic = messageFromOtherArray.lastObject;
                        [self callMsgReadAPI:lastReadMsgDic];
                    }
                } else {
                    if (messageAllArray.count > 0 && isUplaodLastRead == NO) {
                        isUplaodLastRead = YES;
                        NSDictionary *lastReadMsgDic = messageAllArray.lastObject;
                        [self callMsgReadAPI:lastReadMsgDic];
                    }
                }

                self.chatModel.channelTopic = _topic;

                NSArray *read_arr=resultDataDic[@"read_arr"];
                [self dealMySendMessageReadedWithReadArray:read_arr AndMessageArray:messageAllArray];

                [self saveMessageWithArray:messageAllArray]; //???? Here server sync-up data with local db
           });            
        });
    }
}
```

This lines will sync-up data from server to tableview

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self setupViewWithMessageArray:messageAllArray]; //???? Here server sync-up data with tableview
                });
```

Here below is the method setupViewWithMessageArray

```
- (void)setupViewWithMessageArray:(NSArray *)messageAllArray {
    if (!isFirstTimeUpdate) {
        isFirstTimeUpdate = YES;
        self.chatModel.dataSource = nil;
        [self.chatTableView reloadData];
        self.chatModel.dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self addMessageWithArray:messageAllArray];
        [self.chatTableView reloadData];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.chatModel.dataSource.count-1 inSection:0];
        [self.chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO]; 
    } else {
        [self addMessageWithArray:messageAllArray];
        [self reloadTableViewWithoutMove];
    }
    self.loadIngView.hidden = YES;
    isLoadingData = NO;
    if (_chatRoomType == ChatRoomTypePrivate) {
        if (lastReadMessageId) {
            [self.chatModel setPrivateChatListAllReadFormMessageId:lastReadMessageId];
        }        
    }
}
```

This line will sync-up data from server to local db

```
[self saveMessageWithArray:messageAllArray]; //???? Here server sync-up data with local db
```

Here below is the method saveMessageWithArray

```
- (void)saveMessageWithArray:(NSArray *)messageArray {
    for (NSDictionary *myDic in messageArray) {
        if (![[FMDBManager sharedInstance] didMessageExistWithMessageID:[myDic objectForKey:@"messageId"]]) {
            [[FMDBManager sharedInstance] SaveMessage:myDic];
        }
        else {
            NSString *mid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myDic[@"messageId"]];
            NSString *isRead = myDic[@"isReaed"];
            if (isRead) {
                [[FMDBManager sharedInstance] UpdateisReadWithMessageID:mid];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So I think now my question is how I can update messageAllArray with arrayToDelete before server sync-up?

Comment: Nothing in the code or description you've given has anything to do with MQTT, it only talks about your app code and possibly SQLite. Update the question with why you think this is MQTT related and example code on how you subscribe and publish messages

Comment: @hardillb I will sure update the question. I'm trying to understand the code related to MQTT for this question but now I don't know which part of the code is relevant. I'm guessing that now I have deleted the messages in local db by the method deleteMessageByMessageId but once I get out and re-enter the chatroom view those messages are still there. I'm not sure if somewhere connects to broker and sync up data from server in which those messages are not deleted (they're only deleted in local db). Please bear with me this is my very first time with MQTT.

Comment: You really need to edit the question and add the code that publishes the messages.